# anyone to help me convert stdClass Object to an array in php

Tags: php

```
      stdClass Object ( [Order] => stdClass Object 
    ( [id] => c62f5d272ghjjgd346lmn34 
    [type] => [status] => placed 
    [keys_status] => Keys were generated )
 [Products] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [name] => Mobile Security 
[devices] => 1 [months] => 12 [quantity] => 1 [msrp_price] => 9 [discount] => 0.0 [end_user_price] => 9 [reseller_margin] => 0.0 [reseller_price] => 9.01[partner_margin] => 90 [partner_price] => 0.9[Keys] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 21 [product_name] => Mobile Security [key] => 1234) ) ) ) [Customer] => stdClass Object ( [name] => IPPS [phone] => 25667587576 [address] => Bishop willis Street [contact_person] => Mukama Gordon [city] => Kigali [zipcode] => 250 [country_id] => 202 [state_id] => [email] => mukamatest@test.com ) [Keys] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [product_id] => 21 [product_name] => Mobile Security [key] => 1234 ) ) )
```

Comment: An object is not an array, you cannot simply convert it. So the question is _why_, or to what purpose you want to do so...

Comment: Uisng simple type casting? `$myArray = (array) $myObject; array_walk_recursive($myArray, function(&$value) { $value = (array) $value; });`

Comment: I would like to convert it into an array so as to pick the customer array details as shown in the object

Comment: Why can't you just pick them from the object? Why do you haver to convert it to an array instead? e.g. `echo $myStandardObject->Order->status;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a really hacky way of doing it, but try

`$arrayversion = json_decode(json_encode($objectversion), true);`

Then

`print_r($arrayversion);` will be an array.